# Ace editor: disable vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ace-editor

I would like to eliminate the vertical scrollbar in my Ace Editor (that I’m embedding in a Ruby on Rails platform). I understand how to *hide* it (given the methods provided through the editor API), but not how to eliminate the capability altogether (which I believe must be done in the editor’s actual javascript). Basically, I would like an editor of a fixed length/number of lines, to which no additional lines may be added by a user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To make editor height exactly 25 lines use

```
editor.setOption({minLines: 25, maxLines: 25})
```

to not allow users to insert text that is more than 25 lines, you can do

```
editor.on("beforeEndOperation", function() {
    if (editor.session.getLength() > 25) {
        editor.session.markUndoGroup()
        editor.undo()
        // alert("25 line demon says: 'never do this again!'")
    }
})
```

but this is rather unfriendly for the users, displaying a warning is much better